# Python Emails Being Duplicated

Tags: python

My script is duplicating my emails when I print print(ggg_email). Im guessing the error is in my ggglastHourMessages. Not sure if im just getting the last 48 hours for the ReceivedTime. Can someone explain if Im doing something wrong there ?

expected results:

```
Test Email
```

actual :

```
Test Email
Test Email
```

code:

```
def readEmail():
    
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        folder = outlook.Folders.Item('SharedMailbox, TEST-Investigation')
        inbox = folder.Folders.Item('Inbox')
        subfolder = inbox.Folders.Item('BoA ICL Ack Notifications')
        messages = subfolder.Items

        lastHourDateTime = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=48)

        ggglastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') + "'")
    
        ggg_emails_l = []

        for ggg_email in ggglastHourMessages:
            if 'P2 Cust ID 1111111 File' in ggg_email.Subject:
                print(ggg_email)
```

Comment: Ugh... why are you mixing `camelCase` (inconsistently—why no capital in `ggglast`?) and `snake_case` for your functions and variables? `read_email()`, `last_hour_date_time`, and `ggg_last_hour_messages` would be more idiomatic (though I have no idea what `ggg` is supposed to be). Please consider complying with Python's official style guide, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @Chris Sorry i got used to java and carried it here. I also changed variable names for privacy reasons.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the script. Maybe you just have multiple emails with the same subject, like all the emails in a thread.

Comment: @Barmar I really thought of that the last hour or so trying to fix this. I searched in outlook at the subject is only coming out once in the actual outlook GUI. is there another way to instead of giving it a TimeDellta, that i can givei it an actual date llike >=2020-12-7?

Comment: It's not even clear what it's printing when you do `print(ggg_email)`. It's not the subject, since the subject has to contain `P2 Cust ID 111111 File`. I'm not familiar with the library you're using, so I'm not sure what you should be doing differently.